# Need edit profile link in the menu for logged in users

Tags: plugin-development, login, profiles, logout

I have a page called edit profile, i have installed the profile builder plugin,so the users can edit their profile from front end, if the user is logged in i want to show the edit profile and logout else it is login. how can i achieve that? i am using wp-bootstrap responsive theme, i am new in wordpress development any one please help me.Do i need to change any thing in the header.php file?

Comment: Please check the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in to check if the user is logged in or not and use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user to get the current user details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current user's info by using `wp_get_current_user()` and then get the profile edit link by using the `user's ID` as following:

```
 function wpse_125929_login_logout( $items ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $profile_edit_url = admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $current_user->ID );
        $profile_link = '<li><a href="' . $profile_edit_url . '">Edit Profile</a></li>';
        $logout_url = '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Logout</a></li>';
        $items = $items. $profile_link. $logout_url;   
    } else {
        $login_link = '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
        $items = $items. $login_link;
    }  
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse_125929_login_logout' );
```

Comment: i am using wp-bootsstrap theme, i a default menu, how i can add the edit profile, logout links to the menu?

Comment: @Naveen I have modified the answer. Now it will append the edit profile link as well as the logout link to the primary menu for logged in user otherwise Login link for guest user.